# Refused to set Unsafe header "Cookie" Hybrid App

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cookies

I am creating an hybrid mobile application using HTML5, CSS3, jQuery and cordova.

In application calling an servlet by `$.ajax` with `xhr.setRequestHeader`. The code is below;

```
var userId = "testuser";
var userPin = "userpin";

var cookieData = "username=" + userId;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: WEB_SERVICE_URL,
   data: {
        "EVENT_ID": "LOGIN",
        "userPin": userPin,
        "isHybrid": "H"
   },
   xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
   beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", cookieData);
   },
   success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        stopActivity();
   },
   error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        stopActivity();
   }
});
```

Facing **Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"** error in console. In request header cookie is not set.

How to resolve the issue in client side?

Comment: If you are just sending user id, why dont you send it as part of post data? Else try out cookie master cordova plugin

Comment: @Gandhi, thanks for your reply. Server side functionality already written as like getting username from request header.

Comment: I used cookie master cordova plugin, refused unsafe cookie problem resolved... Thanks @Gandhi

Comment: Will post the answer, please accept and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [cordova cookie master plugin](https://github.com/edwardgaoyb/cordova-cookie-master) should resolve your issue. This plugin allows you to get and set cookie values from your WebView through a simple interface. This plugin is supported in both Android and iOS platforms.